# How do you call a function from another file in Python Lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

Using Python on Lambda AWS
Trying to call a function in another file.
One file is called Constants.
The other file has the line import Constants 
This returns an error
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
Google searching did not help
Suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like your problem isn't in _calling_ the function but rather _importing_ it. Can you please show the full error message?

Comment: "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'" is the full error message  there is also Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'Constants'

Comment: Please don't put it in the comments. You can [edit] your question to add more information.